# бургер правого меню открывает левое меню

Tags: html, css, меню

Я сделал одно меню "(https://www.mobila.name/post/53eb5a219dcff/)"и все отлично работает. Потом создал еще одно такое же меню и завернул их оба в див класс left-cb и right-sb. Естественно попутно создав в папке sass два файла и подключил их к общему sass (@import 'Left-SB.sass' и @import 'Right-SB.sass'). 
И ... что у нас получается? А ничего! левое меню и его бургер работает а правое нет. Показателем того что правое меню подключено является то что есть еще один бургер справа на экране и само поломанное меню. Но нет, поломанное меню это еще пол проблемы, если бы оно было под управлением своего бургера ( как вы уже поняли оно вообще никак не управляется). А основная проблема состоит в том что этот правый бургер открывает и закрывает левое меню а правому хоть бы хны.
Как сделать чтобы бургер открывал правое меню, а его меню отображалось не поломанно а правильно(так же как и левое) ?

```css
.left-sb {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.left-sb .hidden-menu-ticker {
  display: none;
}

.left-sb .btn-menu-l {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 351px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: left .23s;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.left-sb .btn-menu-l span {
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 3px 0 0 -3px;
  transition: all .1s linear .23s;
  position: relative;
}

.left-sb .btn-menu-l span.firsts {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.left-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-l:checked ~ .btn-menu-l {
  left: 360px;
  top: 50px;
}

.left-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-l:checked ~ .hidden-menu-l {
  left: 0;
}

.left-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-l:checked ~ .btn-menu-l span.first-l {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 10px;
}

.left-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-l:checked ~ .btn-menu-l span.second-l {
  opacity: 0;
}

.left-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-l:checked ~ .btn-menu-l span.third-l {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -10px;
}

.left-sb .hidden-menu-l {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 360px;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -360px;
  transition: left .2s;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.right-sb {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}

.right-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-r {
  display: none;
}

.right-sb .btn-menu-r {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: 351px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: right .23s;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.right-sb .btn-menu-r span {
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 3px 0 0 -3px;
  transition: all .1s linear .23s;
  position: relative;
}

.right-sb .btn-menu-r span.first {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.right-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-r:checked ~ .btn-menu-r {
  right: 360px;
  top: 50px;
}

.right-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-r:checked ~ .hidden-menu-r {
  right: 0;
}

.right-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-r:checked ~ .btn-menu-r span.first-r {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 10px;
}

.right-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-r:checked ~ .btn-menu-r span.second-r {
  opacity: 0;
}

.right-sb .hidden-menu-ticker-r:checked ~ .btn-menu-r span.third-r {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: -10px;
}

.right-sb .hidden-menu-r {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 360px;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: -360px;
  transition: right .2s;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

* {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
  background-color: pink;
  max-width: 1170px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #d0f;
}

main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: #e00;
}

main .button-RN {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 120px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 80px;
}

main #leftNav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
  left: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 500px;
}

main #leftNav .my-menu ul li {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

main .button-LN {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 120px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 80px;
}

main #rightNav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
  right: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 500px;
}

main #rightNav .my-menu ul li {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

footer {
  background-color: #d0f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/libs.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

<!--  <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("[data-toggle]").click(function() {
      var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
      $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
    });
  });//]]>
 </script> -->

</head>
<body>
 
 <header>
  header
 </header>

 <main>


  <div class="left-sb">
   <input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker-l">
   <label class="btn-menu-l" for="hmt">
     <span class="first-l"></span>
     <span class="second-l"></span>
     <span class="third-l"></span>
   </label>
   <ul class="hidden-menu-l">
     <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>  
     <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>  
   </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="right-sb">
   <input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker-r">
   <label class="btn-menu-r" for="hmt">
     <span class="first-r"></span>
     <span class="second-r"></span>
     <span class="third-r"></span>
   </label>
   <ul class="hidden-menu-R">
     <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>  
     <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>  
   </ul>
  </div>


  <!-- <div class="conta left-sb">
     <div id="sidebar">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="main-content">
       <a href="#" data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle">
         <span class="bar"></span>
         <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
       </a>
    </div>
  </div> -->



  <div id="content" class="container">
   section 
  </div>
<!--   <button class="button-RN" onclick="OnOffRightNav()">tytdrsf</button>

  <div id="leftNav">
   <button class="button-LN" onclick="OnOffLeftNav()">kljkljlk</button>
   <nav class="my-menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li class="active"><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>

  <div id="rightNav">
   <nav class="my-menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li class="active"><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> -->
 </main>
 <footer>
  footer
 </footer>
 
 <script src="js/libs.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/common.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас на странице 2 input с одинаковым id. Поскольку, правЫй label привязан к input с id="hmt", он находит первЫй input и изменяет его состояние. Поэтому у вас открывается левое меню. Измените id у input.hidden-menu-ticker-r и аттрибут for у правого lable.btn-menu-r.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker-r">
        <label class="btn-menu-r" for="hmt">
```